# Compile OpenThread for a [ Host / 802.15.4 Controller ] arrangement

Tags: openthread

On the official OpenThread / Platforms site it lists basically 3 way to use the OT stack.
(https://openthread.io/platforms/)

The first runs on a single device, the second communicates with the OT stack via Spinel and the third option splits the OT stack somewhat in the middle. (https://openthread.io/platforms/#host--802154-controller)

I have been looking for a way to build the third option, but i haven't found one. The configure script allows me to choose the following:

```
--enable-[cli, ncp]-app=[no, mtd, ftd]
```

That covers the first two options mentioned, but not the Host / Controller arrangement.

--

Do i need to write it myself? (That would not be a problem, but i do not want to write it again)

If i am missing some obvious configure options would you kindly point me to them?

Comment: I am still interested in any help btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are ongoing efforts in the OpenThread project to support the Host / Controller configuration.

1. Supporting a radio-only NCP mode using the existing platform APIs: https://github.com/openthread/openthread/pull/2085
2. Developing a platform abstraction for 802.15.4 MLME-SAP and MCPS-SAP.